# How to use REGEXP in `sqlite-net-pcl` in UWP

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, sqlite-net

I have a `UWP` project that works with `Sqlite` database. I added `sqlite-net-pcl` to my references.
I want to use `REGEXP` in `select` query but it gives me the `no such function: REGEXP`.
I searched the error but the results are about `SQLiteFunction` that is not defined here.
what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the end I installed `sqlite-net-pcl` from `nuget` not the one in the `Universal windows extensions` in ReferenceManger.

`sqlite-net-pcl` package in nuget has `sqlite3_create_function` method.

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(@"myDB.db");
SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_create_function(con.Handle, "REGEXP", 2, null, MatchRegex);

private void MatchRegex(sqlite3_context ctx, object user_data, sqlite3_value[] args)
    {
        bool isMatched = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_value_text(args[1]), SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_value_text(args[0]),RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (isMatched)
            SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_result_int(ctx, 1);
        else
            SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_result_int(ctx, 0);
    }
```

this works fine :)

Comment: Wow! Didn't notice `SQLite-net PCL` is built upon `SQLitePCL.raw`. `sqlite3_create_function` method actually is not a method of `SQLite-net PCL` but the method in `SQLitePCL.raw`. Anyway, a great solution for this problem. ;)

Comment: All I was missing was a call to `utf8_to_string()`, as in `SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_value_text( args[ 0 ] ).utf8_to_string()`

Answer (score 2):

Ref [The LIKE, GLOB, REGEXP, and MATCH operators](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The REGEXP operator is a special syntax for the regexp() user function. No regexp() user function is defined by default and so use of the REGEXP operator will normally result in an error message. If an [application-defined SQL function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) named "regexp" is added at run-time, then the "X REGEXP Y" operator will be implemented as a call to "regexp(Y,X)".

So to use REGEXP, we need be able to create user-defined functions. And [SQLiteFunction](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/e7e8109be704648c) is the class that designed to handle user-defined functions easily in [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org). However System.Data.SQLite is an ADO.NET provider for SQLite that can't be used in UWP apps.

In [SQLite-net PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/), there is no such method. However, SQLite-net PCL uses [SQLitePCL.raw](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw) underneath, which is a very thin C# wrapper around the C API for SQLite and provides low-level (raw) access to SQLite. With SQLitePCL.raw, we can create user-defined functions as what in @Maryam's answer.

Comment: Here is something for Entity Framework: https://sudonull.com/post/92575-How-to-make-friends-Linq-to-Entities-and-Regex

Answer (score 0):

If you can use something like SQLite PCL Pretty, you can do the following (may work with other PCLs, not sure though):

```
using System;
using SQLitePCL.pretty;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TestSqlite
{ 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<ISQLiteValue, ISQLiteValue, ISQLiteValue> regexFunc =
                        (ISQLiteValue val, ISQLiteValue regexStr) =>
                        {
                            if (Regex.IsMatch(Convert.ToString(val), Convert.ToString(regexStr)))
                                return true.ToSQLiteValue();
                            return false.ToSQLiteValue();
                        };
            SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();
            SQLiteDatabaseConnection _dbcon = SQLiteDatabaseConnectionBuilder
                        .InMemory
                        .WithScalarFunc("REGEXP", regexFunc)
                        .Build();
            string sql = "CREATE TABLE foo (a int, b text);";
            _dbcon.ExecuteAll(sql);
            _dbcon.ExecuteAll(@"INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 'this is me');
                                INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2, 'that is me');
                                INSERT INTO foo VALUES (3, 'he is me');");
            sql = "SELECT * FROM foo where '\\w{4} is me' REGEXP b;";
            foreach (var row in _dbcon.Query(sql)) { Console.WriteLine(row[1].ToString()); }
        }
    }
}
```